# Laravel set up - SSL error

Tags: php, laravel, ssl, iis

I use PHP(5.6.24) with IIS7. I am trying to set up laravel but getting below errors.

> The openssl extension is required for SSL/TLS protection but is not
>   available. If you can not enable the openssl extension, you can
>   disable this error , at your own risk, by setting the 'disable-tls'
>   option to true.

SSL extension is enabled in PHP.ini file.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have `php_openssl.dll` on `ext` dir
Path could be
`php\ext\php_openssl.dll`

The path may differ if you are using xampp.

if you could not find it then download from here

http://www.opendll.com/index.php?file-download=php_openssl.dll&arch=32bit&version=5.4.3.0

Then move it to `ext` dir

Then change `php_openssl.dll` path in `php.ini`

```
; Directory in which the loadable extensions (modules) reside.
; extension_dir = "./" #path should match ext dir
; On windows:
extension_dir = "ext"

...
extension=php_openssl.dll
```

Comment: Using windows or linux?

Comment: this link may help you https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-to-install-openssl-php-extension-mbstring-php-extension-tokenizer-php-extension-in-centos-7-0-x64 if you are using linux and you should have `yum`

Comment: Please check whether you have `opensll` in `ext` dir  for example `php\ext\php_openssl.dll`

Comment: Problem could be either you dont have `open_ssl` or its configured wrong

Comment: @kreya i have updated answer. please check it. this will help surely.

Comment: Thanks but again no luck.

Comment: That should work else you are doing something wrong.  found `openssl.dll` in respective folder?

Answer (score 0):

First of all install **XAMPP** or **WAMP**. I'm using XAMPP though.

Search the **php folder** in XAMPP and add it to the environment variables of your system (WINDOWS). You can find it by searching in the windows search bar.

I'll suppose you did the others installations required for laravel.

Then to fix the problem you'll have to uncomment a line in the XAMPP php folder, in the file : **php.ini**.

Go to **php.ini** and uncomment the line **;extension=openssl** by retrieving the semi-colon **";"**.

After this it should be working good!